# What happens to a device context when its window is closed?

Tags: visual-c++, gdi

I have a VS2019 app using MFC, it reads pixels from the client area of another Windows app. So I find the target window using `EnumWindows()` and get its window handle `hWnd` , then I get a device context for that window by doing `hDC = GetDC(hWnd)`, and then every few seconds I do `BitBlt(..., hDC /*sourceDC*/, ...)` to read pixels from the target window. After calling `GetDC(hWnd)`, I have to call `ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC)` eventually to release the device context. But what happens if the target app has closed by then and `hWnd` isn't a valid window handle any more? Do I still have to call `ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC)`? Or can I assume that the device context disappeared when the window disappeared?

Comment: What if that window is closed before you call `BitBlt`? Or better yet - during that call?